# Anonymous Followers on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to follow someone anonymously on Facebook?

Sometimes I see their list of followers, but is that list complete?

How is it possible to follow someone without appearing in the list of followers?

---

**to clarify**: Within the Facebook website I expect this is not possible.  I wondered if there are any FB-related apps that can do this?  There are certainly apps which can integrate social media feeds or read public FB pages.

Comment: Always post separate questions as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge it is not possible. No one can follow someone without appearing in the followers list.

When you click on follow button, automatically you get appear in followers list.

Comment: You can give us more scenario that how is you seeing anonymous followers to get more detailed answer. Following anonymously is not possible.